# Tried to add custom UIBarButtonItem to UIToolBar, but item comes out messed up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I'm trying to add a custom button (shape and color) to my UIToolBar, but it comes out much differently than it should.

What button looks like:

[image]

What it looks like in the bar:

[image]

Here's the code I used to add it:

```
    UIImage *backButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back-button.png"];
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:backButtonImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(backButtonTapped)];
    [toolBarItems addObject:backButton];
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `initWithCustomView:` instead of the other initialization method

So you should first create a UIButton with the custom image and selector you want and then use this piece of code

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourButton];
[toolBarItems addObject:backButton];
```